# Spaces that accept Turing Machines as points

Tags: logic

I know that is a naive question, but are there any mathematical spaces whose points consist of Turing Machines?

Answer (score 2):

Let's identify Turing machines with natural numbers via your favorite indexing scheme. The *positive topology* on $\mathbb{N}$ then has as basis the sets $$\{e: F\subseteq W_e\}$$ for $F\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ finite, where "$W_e$" denotes the $e$th c.e. set (that is, the set of inputs on which $\Phi_e$ halts). Note that this is really a topology on c.e. sets, rather than on Turing machines - if $W_c=W_d$, then $c$ and $d$ are in exactly the same open sets (so in particular this space is not $T_0$, although we can fix this by instead thinking of this as a topology on the c.e. sets rather than their indices).

This topology, if I recall correctly, has some applications to priority arguments (Lachlan wrote some notes on topology for priority arguments, which I'm trying to get a hold of) and the theory of **isols** (see [here](http://ac.els-cdn.com/016800729290067A/1-s2.0-016800729290067A-main.pdf?_tid=1c59391a-c098-11e6-8e8d-00000aacb362&acdnat=1481567202_bdaf054f965148040b4cf638a343d940) or [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1969-144-00/S0002-9947-1969-0262081-5/S0002-9947-1969-0262081-5.pdf)); I'll post some specific links illustrating this application when I have time (and if my recollection is correct).

Comment: I have to learn so many things to grasp your answer :) Moreover, this means my question is not useless :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what kind of "spaces" you are interested in. In "Russian style" or "Markov style" computable/constructive analysis, real numbers are identified with algorithms: to give someone a real number means to give them an algorithm to compute that number.  So in this framework the "points" on the real line are, in some sense, Turing machines.

This causes several differences compared to classical analysis. The first is that equality is intensional, rather than extensional. Two different Turing machines can compute the same real numbers, so it is necessary to distinguish between having two different algorithms compares to having two genuinely different real numbers. This is a common feature of constructive systems.

The second change is that, because all real numbers are (by definition) computable in this framework, some classically valid results become invalid. For example, in this framework a [Specker sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specker_sequence) simply does not converge, so the theorem that simply states "a bounded increasing sequence of rationals must converge" is false.  If we additionally require a computable modulus of convergence, then the theorem becomes true.  This is a second common feature of constructive mathematics: sometimes classical theorems require additional information to become constructively valid.

Comment: I am just a beginner of mathematical logic. As there are function spaces, I wondered if there any Turing Machine spaces. Your answer helps a great deal, thanks.